# Pandas "Consecutive"/Rolling Percent Rank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I create a "consecutive"/rolling percent rank on a pandas df series with a rolling window that grows as the data frame row count grows- as opposed to being a fixed window.  rolling() requires an integer for the window size.

I basically want the ranking to be consecutively calculated as opposed to running the ranking function across the entire series and outputting the results. First row would have a rank just on that one row. By the end of the data frame, the rank would be calculated across the entire series.

Desired dataframe output:

| Index | Value | Rank (descending) | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6 | 1 | 6 is the first row so rank on 6 is 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 is the second largest value between 6 and 3 so rank is 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 is the second largest value between 6,3, and 4 so rank is 2 |
| 3 | 100 | 1 | 100 is the largest value in the series of 6,3,4,100 so rank is 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 | 1 is the smallest value in series of 6,3,4,100,1 so rank is last as 5 |

My thinking:

```
df['len']=range(len(df))
df['rank']=df['value'].rolling(df['len']).rank(pct=True)
```

Comment: need more clear question and desired output

Comment: I want a rolling rank with a window size = current row index value. So the window size grows

Comment: Make a table of the desired output and include a part in the text that explains why the output is that way based on the data in the example. If the table in the text is the desired output, please explain why the result is like that for each row.

Comment: Let me know if the edit helps clarify

Comment: Is there no maximum number in the rolling window number? I thought no and left an answer. If not, use `expanding` rather than `rolling` to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([6, 3, 4, 100, 1], columns=['value'])
```

`df`

```
    value
0   6
1   3
2   4
3   100
4   1
```

**Code**

```
df.assign(rank=df['value'].expanding().rank(ascending=False).astype('int'))
```

output:

```
    value   rank
0   6       1
1   3       2
2   4       2
3   100     1
4   1       5
```

if you want pct rank use following code

```
df.assign(rank_pct=df['value'].expanding().rank(ascending=False, pct=True))
```

output:

```
value   rank_pct
0   6   1.000000
1   3   1.000000
2   4   0.666667
3   100 0.250000
4   1   1.000000
```